# How to publish declaration files (.d.ts) for vscode extensions

Tags: typescript, npm, declaration, vscode-extensions, .d.ts

I wrote a vscode extension that exposes an API for use by other extensions (by having the [`activate()`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#extensions) function return a value).

I would like to publish a [scoped](https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm/scope.html) `npm` package that exposes a declaration file (`.d.ts`), that would assist developers of extensions to consume my extension.

My issue is that I cannot reuse the extension's `package.json`, because it doesn't allow for `@` in the package's name ([`vsce package`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#packaging-extensions) fails).

If I create a dedicated `package.json` for the purpose of publishing the declaration file to `npm`, I end up copying the `.d.ts` file and all its dependencies from the extension's `out` directory. This approach seems a bit cumbersome.

I couldn't find documentation that describes the proper way for doing this: publishing vscode extension declaration files to npm (scoped or not).

What is the correct approach to doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

1. I created another folder, that contains no source code, adjacent to the extension's folder.
2. I placed a different `package.json` in it:

   1. I placed my package's scope in the `name` property and suffixed it with `-types` for clarity.
   2. I created a `copy` npm script that copies artifacts from the `out` folder of the extension's folder. This script uses [`ncp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ncp) for cross platform support.
   3. I added `@types/vscode` to the `dependencies` property (not `devDependencies`, as noted in [publishing declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html#dependencies)) because my `.d.ts` file includes a reference to `vscode`.
3. I created a `.npmignore` file to reinclude the `out` folder (using negate: `!out`) that was excluded in the `.gitignore` file.
4. I needed to exclude `.js` files from the `out` folder to avoid errors related to missing transitive dependencies. I could have created another `tsconfig.json` file that emits only `.d.ts` files (using [`emitDeclarationOnly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html#compiler-options)), but ended up using `.npmignore` to do this.

The above works for me, but there must be a better way, right??